# saltstack: archive.extracted template jinja

Tags: salt

I have an archive on my master and want to extract it on the minion. For this it is fine I use :

```
  archive.extracted:
    - name:  'c:\PACKAGE'
    - source: salt://myfile.zip
    - archive_format: zip
    - enforce_toplevel: False
    - failhard: True
```

the problem is that I need to apply jinja template on some files of the zip file content.

But there is no template property on archive.extracted and I can't find a way to apply jinja template after it is extracted on minion server...

any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no much choices regarding your situation, I see two of them :

1. You ask your dev dpt to add your jinja templating to their builds (which may be hard or even impossible)
2. You can use salt module such as `file.append` or `file.replace` to add / replace your jinja code inside (this is not very clean that's the least we can say)

If you'd share an example that may help us to give some good advice